# Is the complex function $f(z) = |z| \sin z$ analytic at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f(z)= |z| \sin z$, where $|z|$ denotes the magnitude or modulus or absolute value of $z$ (the square root of the sum of squares of its real and imaginary parts).

It is easy to see that $f(z)$ is differentiable since if $\delta z \rightarrow 0$ along any path, 
$$
\lim_{\delta z \rightarrow 0}\frac {|0+\delta z| \sin (0+\delta z) - |0|\sin 0}{\delta z} = 0
$$
so the limit definition of the derivative makes good sense.

However, functions involving the absolute value are usually not analytic near the origin.  But here, for example, the contour integral around the unit circle gives the answer $0$, so perhaps it is analytic?

Comment: How do you define a function being analytic at one point?

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos Analytic at a point means differentiable in some open neighborhood of the point. This term is rarely used, but some books define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose it is analytic at the origin. It means it is differentiable at some open ball $B_\epsilon(0)$. If we take a small enough $\epsilon$ then $\sin(z)\ne 0$ in the domain $B_\epsilon(0)\setminus\{0\}$. In that case we can define $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\sin(z)}$ on $B_\epsilon(0)\setminus\{0\}$. It is differentiable there as a quotient of two differentiable functions where the denominator is never zero. But note that $g(z)=|z|$ on $B_\epsilon(0)\setminus\{0\}$. A function which is holomorphic in an open connected domain and its imaginary part is constant must be constant itself. However $|z|$ is not constant on $B_\epsilon(0)\setminus\{0\}$ and that is a contradiction.